# How to use &key and &rest in a cl-defun togather?

Tags: function, elisp

I have a function like this

```
(cl-defun foo (a b c d e &rest f)
  nil)
```

Arguments `c`, `d` and `e` are `nil` 80% of time.

To make it looks better, I do this:

```
(cl-defun foo (a b &rest f &key c d e &allow-other-keys)
  nil)
```

When `c`,`d` and `e` are not provided, it's fine.

However, if one of them is used, `f` gets a wrong argument.
For example:

```
(foo 1 2 :c 6 3 4 5)
;; ==> expected: a=1, b=2, c=6, f= (3 4 5)
;; ==> real case: a=1, b=2, c=6, f= (:c 6 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is the one specified by CommonLisp (actually I'm not sure if your call `(foo 1 2 :c 6 3 4 5)` is even valid in Common-Lisp because I think it would treat 3 and 5 as degenerate *keywords* and the `5` keyword lacks a value).

IOW the list you get via `&rest` includes all the keywords.  So if you don't want them, you have to drop them by hand (at which point you're often better off not using `&key` at all).

Example for removing the keys `c d e` from the list `f`:

```el
(dolist (key '(c d e))
  (cl-remf f key))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(cl-defmacro foo2 (a b &rest f &key c d e &allow-other-keys)
  (let (key rest)
    (dolist (elt f)
      (if (memq elt '(:c :d :e))
          (setq key elt)
        (if key
            (progn
              (set (intern-soft (string-remove-prefix ":" (symbol-name key))) elt)
              (setq key nil))
          (push elt rest))))
    (setq rest (nreverse rest))

    `(foo ,a ,b ,c ,d ,e ,@rest)))

(pp-macroexpand-expression '(foo2 1 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 6 7 8 9))
;; ==> (foo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
(pp-macroexpand-expression '(foo2 1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; ==> (foo 1 2 nil nil nil 3 4 5 6)
(pp-macroexpand-expression '(foo2 1 2 3 4 5 6 :c 7 :d 8 :e 9))
;; ==> (foo 1 2 7 8 9 3 4 5 6)
(pp-macroexpand-expression '(foo2 1 2 3 :c 4 5 :d 6 7 :e 8 9))
;; Extreme case
;; ==> (foo 1 2 4 6 8 3 5 7 9)
```

With @Stefan's suggestion, I come up with this. I am not really good at macro, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but you can use my function:

```lisp
(cl-defun my/filter-keys (&rest rest &key &allow-other-keys)
"Separate &rest and &key arguments. Allows you to use &rest and &key together with &allow-other-keys.

NOTE: This assumes that the args are first then the keys:
\"arg1\" \"arg1\" :key1 t :key2 nil

Return is an alist who's car is a list of args and who's cdr is a
a list of the keys. 

EXAMPLE: If you wanted to use a function that uses &rest and &key.

(cl-defun my/func (&rest rest &key somekey &allow-other-keys )
  \"Example function using &rest and &key\"
  (let* ((result (apply 'my/filter-keys rest))
        (args (car result))
        (keys (cdr result)))
  args))
 
(my/func 1 2 '(3) 4 :sym 'symbol :st t)
⇒ (1 2 (3) 4)

If you change the return to keys:
((:sym symbol) (:st t))
"
(let ((keys '())
     (args '())
     (stop  nil))
(seq-map-indexed (lambda (el idx) (if  (string-match-p "^:" (format "%s" el))
                                       (progn (add-to-list 'keys `(,el ,(nth (+ idx 1) rest)) t) (setq stop t)) 
                                       (unless stop (add-to-list 'args el t)))) rest)
(cons args keys)))
```